# Extracting singleton value from xml list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am familiar with extracting values from xml using SQL in SQL Server, but now I need to identify the parent node with a particular "key node" value and get the value from its "value node."

```
<example>
  <item>
    <key>skip</key>
    <value>True</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <key>test</key>
    <value>True</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <key>number</key>
    <value />
  </item>
  <item>
    <key>country</key>
    <value>USA</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <key>Account Number</key>
    <value>1111111111</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <key>website</key>
    <value>stackoverflow</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <key>type</key>
    <value>Customer</value>
  </item>
</example>
```

If I want to get the account number I could use this sql statement:

```
SELECT xml.value('(example/item/value)[5]','varchar(30)')
```

Since the item node is 5th down on the list, the singleton will be 5. But what if the position of the account number node can change? I want to be able to identify the account number based on the condition that key = 'Account Number.'

In other words, I want to `SELECT value where key = 'Account Number'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to specify WHICH "item" you want in brackets, by specifying a key/value that is unique to the item. In this case, you want the one where the "key" node has the text "Account Number". You'd express it like this:

```
SELECT @xml.value('(example/item[key="Account Number"]/value)[1]','varchar(30)')
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Would you happen to know of any online resources that I can use to learn more about parsing xml in SQL Server?

Comment: In my experience, it's StackOverflow. I had a very similar issue to this, and the only place I found the answer was here. If I ever do find a good source, I'll be sure to let everyone know.